# Is data pulled into memory when building an ADO Recordset?

Tags: c++, ms-access, ado

I've been working on a fairly large C++ project that surprisingly uses MS Access 97 as it's underlying database engine. I notice a lot of instances in the code where recordsets are being created from queries that could potentially return well over 100,000 records.

I'm curious if ADO will pull all that data into memory when you build the recordset, or if it is smarter and is able to only load the data "just in time" when you attempt to read it out of the recordset? We're getting a lot of performance complaints from customers and this looks suspiciously guilty to me.

(Migrating to a newer database engine is on our roadmap. Trust me, no one on the team is happy with Access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with using Access for the database here:

1. Supposedly it supports 255 concurrent users, in reality between 6
   and 20 is the maximum number, with fewer connections as the database
   size/complexity increases.
2. The 2Gb restriction on database size and
3. Yes, the data is cached locally so if you have 5000 results then
   you'll just have to accept them :)

Comment: We are unfortunately more than aware of issues #1 and #2 (and so are a few of our particularly cranky customers). But #3 is where I was personally unsure, but had suspicions. The team is anxious for management to green light a re-write of our DB layer!

Comment: I feel your pain! It's because of these issues that modern practice is to structure code so that the business logic is unaware of the data source, just retrieving data from the datalayer.

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately this code started in 1997 when Access97 was new hotness and before C++98 was finalized! Also, our data layer exposes a lot of implementation details about ADO (including hacks), which is just horrible. I've been dying to rewrite our entire data layer for quite a while now. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm curious if ADO will pull all that data into memory when you build the recordset, or if it is smarter and is able to only load the data "just in time" when you attempt to read it out of the recordset?*

Perhaps fetching the rows asynchronously could improve your users' experience.  See the options from the [ExecuteOptionEnum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676517%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be used with the [ADO Recordset Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I doubt that's what you had in mind for "just in time", but it's the best I can offer.

Seems to me a better design would be to revise the query to retrieve only a subset of the 100K rows.  Then "just in time" could become "let the user request the next subset".  And you should be able to get decent performance from Access with reasonably-sized recordsets.

Comment: Getting a subset is exactly what I intend to do. We're switching to a different engine ASAP, and it should be pretty clear there are deficiencies in our current data layer. My intent is to push for the entire data layer to be rewritten so we could do such appropriate "just in time" retrievals. I have a much larger history in building web applications, and that's how we do it there to get near-instant page loads on large databases. For now, we're stuck cleaning up issues with the existing layer and it made me wonder if ADO in fact caches the data locally when you build a recordset.

Comment: Not that this is on topic, but it seems our data layer attempts to be it's own database engine and manage everything in memory instead of relying on an actual engine to worry about the details. I can understand why since the underlying storage is in Access97, but this is still a terrible idea nonetheless ~_^

Comment: I wonder if we may be talking at cross purposes here.  Your app should use reasonably-sized recordsets regardless of which db engine you choose.  If those huge recordsets are the cause of customer performance complaints, and you want to satisfy the customers sooner rather than later, fix the recordset issue now.  Don't wait until you switch db engines and rewrite the entire data layer.  But first verify your assumption those recordsets are the cause of the complaints.  Make a copy of the db, dump most of the records and see what happens.

Comment: I completely agree. However this codebase is in excess of 2 million lines of C++, and a good chunk of it depends on our data layer. Changing the data layer's underlying implementation would mean a massive amount of test coverage that would take our test team quite a bit of time to complete. We don't have that in the budget just yet. It will be coming "soon", however, where a full rewrite will be possible. The problem is too systemic to tuck under our current budget. I'm adding a new area to the data layer, so rest assured the new functionality will do things properly.

Comment: I'll back off then.  :-)  If the effort isn't unreasonable, see whether fetching the data asynchronously improves your users' experience.  And I would still verify the assumption that the performance problems are caused by the size of those recordsets ... that should be easy to test and not require any c++ code changes.

Comment: I'll definitely give the asynchronous retrieval a shot. I asked the original question as a sanity check before bothering to test the size of recordsets. The fact that ADO does cache everything is just more fuel for our team to justify a rewrite of the data layer when we switch engines.